# How do I find the number of distinct elements in a certain set?

Tags: functions

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be distinct reals and $A = \{f_1(t), f_2(t), \ldots, f_n(t)\}$, where $t$ is real. The functions $f_k$ are defined by

$$
f_k(t) = 
\cases{
1, & when $t>=x_k $\cr
0, & otherwise
}
$$
How many distinct elements does A contain?

Comment: `fk[t]=xi*HeavisideTheta[t - xi]` are n difference functions if x1,x2,...,xn are  n difference real numbers.

Comment: `Table[Plot[i*HeavisideTheta[x - i], {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> Hue[Rescale[i, {.1, .9}]], 
  PlotRange -> All], {i, {1, 4, 7.1, 9}}]`

Comment: It can either be one or two (either the entire set contains just a $0/1$, or it is $\{0,1\}$)

Comment: You are missing a right parenthesis in your definition of $A$.  I presume it should be just inside the right brace, so $A$ is a set of $n-$tuples

Comment: I wrote it a set builder form but someone edited it. There should be no left parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

When $t$ is less than all the $x$s all the functions are $0$.  When $t$ is greater than all of them they are all $1$.  As $t$ increases it converts each entry from $0$ to $1$ at a different point, and once an entry is converted it stays $1$, so each element of $A$ is distinct and there are $n$ of them.

Comment: my question is How many distinct elements does A contain?

Comment: What you consider an "distinct element". A is a n-vector function. Each component is a Heaviside function. You can also say that each component is a piecewise functions with 2 pieces. Going from t=0 .. 1 each component makes a jump somewhere (at the xi)